# Trying to exit script with a status code but getting "unexpected end of file"

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit, syntax

I'm using bash shell on Amazon Linux.  I can't figure out why my script is dying with a syntax error.  My script ends like so

```
chmod 775 $TFILE2
output_file=$( create_test_results_file "$TFILE2" )
(cat $TFILE2; uuencode $output_file $output_file) | mailx -s "$subject" "$to_email"
rm $output_file
echo "sent second email"

#Cleanup
rm $TFILE1
rm $TFILE2
echo "removed files"

# If node exited unsuccessfully, verify we alert the process above.
if [ $rc1 != 0 ]; then exit $rc1 fi
if [ $rc2 != 0 ]; then exit $rc2 fi
```

and when I run it, it prints out the last two echo statements, but then seems to die after that

```
sent second email
removed files
/home/jboss/.jenkins/jobs/springboard/workspace/automated-tests/nodejs/run_tests.sh: line 86: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Can anyone tell me why its dying with the unexpected end of file error?

Comment: If there is no code after the block shown here, you could write the last line simply as `exit $rc2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that `fi` needs to be a separate command, so you need semi-colons:

```
if [ $rc1 != 0 ]; then exit $rc1; fi
if [ $rc2 != 0 ]; then exit $rc2; fi
```

You should quote your variables, and since you’re comparing integers, use the appropriate operator:

```
if [ "$rc1" -ne 0 ]; then exit "$rc1"; fi
if [ "$rc2" -ne 0 ]; then exit "$rc2"; fi
```

although the behaviour here is slightly different: empty values will be considered equal to 0 (where `!=` would consider them different).